# Python 3.6.0 Class Inheritance

Tags: python

```
class Animal:
def __init__(self, name, species): 
    self.name = name
    self.species = species

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSpecies(self):
        return self.species

    def __del__(self):
        print ("This came from del method")


class Dog(Animal):
    pass
    def __init__(self, name, isBig):
        Animal.__init__(self, name, "Dog")
        self.isBig = isBig
```

I've been playing around with understanding Classes and Child Classes and ran into the following. When instantiating

```
dog = Dog("Bob", True)
```

and try to access the method getName() from the parent, Animal, class I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
dog.getName()
AttributeError: Dog instance has no attribute 'getName'
```

What is preventing me from directly accessing methods of the parent class?

Comment: Works for me when I fix your indentation: https://repl.it/repls/PleasingRealisticEel

Comment: Your indentation is broken here and probably wrong in your task code. I expect you won't be able to access getName on a base Animal instance either.

Comment: I indented your code in an edit and it should work fine. Please close this if it does work

Comment: Also note, writing getters and setters is not Pythonic.

Comment: One of the first things you should have learned when starting Python is that it's **critical** to get the indentation correct.

Comment: @JacobIRR please don't edit broken code to fix it, that will make all these comments look wrong. Post an answer or a comment instead.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - that seems reasonable. Should it be said that the function of editing is meant for non-fixing cases only then?

Comment: Not 100% of the time, you can fix errors in your own answers for example. Just don't edit out the problem in a question, or fix other peoples' answers beyond simple typos (etiquette is to comment for anything more serious).

Comment: Yes, indentation was it. Still slips by me sometimes. Thanks all for helping point that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that indentation matters in Python!

Here's what your code should look like for all the methods to be in the `Animal` class:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, species): 
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSpecies(self):
        return self.species

    def __del__(self):
        print ("This came from del method")
```

If you miss an indentation block, Python thinks you're done with your class definition.